# iOS BLE UART Data Transmission Problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using an Adafruit BLE UART board to transmit data to an iOS application for processing. On the iOS side, data is being processed by a class called [UARTPeripheral](https://github.com/Pinoccio/client-ios-pinoccio/blob/master/Pinoccio/View%20Controllers/UARTPeripheral.h). (The link I sent is to the file in some one's GitHub project - I can't find a link to the real thing - but the file is the same. The Arduino side is processing the data with an [Adafruit library](https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-the-adafruit-bluefruit-le-uart-friend/software). The things that require scrutiny on each side (at least I think) are the `print()` function on the Arduino side and the `- (void)didReceiveData:(NSData*)newData` method on the iOS side.

Here's the actual problem that crops up when I try and send data (from the Arduino side): between every data value is a 3. Simple as that. Say I send a binary 2 from the board using `ble.print(B00000010)`, on the iOS side I receive `32`. Say I use the following code to send an integer from the Arduino side:

```
int test = 4132;
ble.print(test);
```

I would end up getting `34313332` on the iOS side. I'm not asking anyone to scrutinize the libraries, but it would be nice to have some indication as to why something like this what happen. I know I could just use the "sticking plaster" approach and just get rid of the 3s, but I would like to find the root of this problem.

Comment: If you print the Int 4132 you are actually sending the string "4132" - so the bytes you have shown correspond to the ASCII values for the characters 4 1 3 2

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'll try casting it as an NSString first. I Should've seen that!

Comment: You probably are receiving an NSData instance so a simple cast won't work, but there are initialisers for String that take NSData

Comment: Yeah - It is NSData, but converting it to NSString with UTF-8 encoding works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the problem - the print() function casts all the values as their ASCII numbers, so it would make sense that all numbers are preceded by 3s, because ASCII numbers are in the 30s range. All I needed to do was to convert the `NSData` to `NSString` with a `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.